# Transfer data between two devices on different routers on the same modem

Tags: networking, router, modem

[image]
I have two devices, a PC and a RaspberryPi, that are connected to two different routers (one has VPN, one does not), that are connected to the same modem. (See diagram). The two routers are physically separated, so it would be difficult to connect them with a cable.

I am trying to access the RaspberryPi from my PC using SSH to run programs remotely on the Pi, and have the Pi send data that the program scrapes back to my PC for processing.

My question is, is this possible? And if so, how would I be able to implement it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this working (prior to my network reconfigure).
What I did was set router A as DHCP server.
Router B was configured as not to hand out IP Addresses.

Connect router A and router B on the LAN side.

All clients went through Router A, unless the devices' IP Settings were changed. I only changed gateway to router B to have the secondary connection.